# How do I fix "No module named 'pyarrow._plasma'"?

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I'm trying to import pandarallel.
During import I'm getting this error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\plasma.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pyarrow._plasma import (ObjectID, ObjectNotAvailable, # noqa

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow._plasma'
```

pyarrow version: '0.13.0'
Using Windows 10

Error doesn't occur in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [plasma windows issue](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/1531) thread on github, plasma is not supported on Windows Operating System. This post dates back to January 2018, but since then there are no changelogs saying that something changed about it.

Then in February 2018 they added a note [plasma is not supported on windows](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/1641)

> - As present, Plasma is only supported for use on Linux and macOS.

Comment: try out dask it works with pandas, numpy and other packages https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial

Comment: A guide tutorial here: https://towardsdatascience.com/trying-out-dask-dataframes-in-python-for-fast-data-analysis-in-parallel-aa960c18a915

Comment: tried dask few months ago.. converting back to pandas even if the dataframe is small takes a lot of time..